# Update row content in android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and I need to update the content of specifics rows without reload all the ListView content.This ListView can be big.

For example (for do it simple) I need to change the content of a TextView (label3 in the adapter) located in a view (the row) at the 'x' position of the adapter. Actually I work with a TouchListView (Commonsware) adapter.

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FavoriteObject> {
    IconicAdapter() {
        super(FavoritesMainActivity.this, R.layout.favbusrow, array);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

            ListFav lf = (listFav) array.get(position).getContent();

            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.favrow,parent, false);
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.busNameF);
            label.setText(lf.getName());
            label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            label.setTypeface(FontsManager.getBoldFont());

            TextView label2 =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.busNumberF);
            label2.setText(lf.getNumber());
            label2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            label2.setTypeface(FontsManager.getBoldFont());

            TextView label3 =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.busDirectionF);
            label3.setText(lf.getQuickName());
            label3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            label3.setTypeface(FontsManager.getRegularFont());

        return(row);
    }
}
```

Someone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You really haven't given enough information for a solid answer. Is the list long? Are you only updating this one field? What kind of adapter are you using?

Comment: It is possible to get access of the content of a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to change the content of a TextView (label3 in the adapter) located in a view (the row) at the 'x' position of the adapter.

That position may or may not be in view. You can use `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` to see if it is, then calculate the child index and use `getChildAt()` to retrieve the row.

You also need to ensure that your data model reflects this change, so as the user scrolls, they do not "lose" whatever direct-to-UI modification you make.

Answer (score 2):

Update the data set within your adapter to reflect your changes and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.